# How to upload a file to KeystoneJS server

Tags: file-upload, keystonejs, formidable

I'm trying to upload a csv file to KeystoneJS (I want to parse the rows and add the records to my MongoDB), but this is getting harder than I though.

Following some examples using "formidable" package (latest, preinstalled with Keystone 4) but it seems the file never reaches my route: Firstly the "on progress" gets fired giving expected size, but just never happens and finally the "oa aborted" event gets fired.

I'm working locally and uploading like 700kb files so no timeout problem. It seems somehow related to this :

[KeystoneJS file upload not working in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454860/keystonejs-file-upload-not-working-in-my-app)

which has not been solved (like any other similar request I found around).

Anyone can help on this?

route js file:

```
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);

    if (req.method.toLowerCase() == "post") {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.type = "multipart"

        /*fs.mkdir("tmp", function(err){
            console.log(err)
        });*/

        form.uploadDir = "tmp";

        form.on("file", function(name, file) {
            console.log(name);
        });
        form.on("error", function(err) {
            console.log(err); // Fires after on abort
        });
        form.on("aborted", function() {
                   // This fires after some time
        });
        form.on("progress", function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
            console.log("PROGRESS"); // this fires once
            console.log(bytesReceived); // 0 here
            console.log(bytesExpected); // actual size here
        });

        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            if (err) return; // this fires on error
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
            var newpath = "../../csv/" + files.filetoupload.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    }

    // Render the view
    else view.render("importPayments");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, after a full day struggling, it happens that you you find the answer right after you posted a question on a forum!

So it was way easier than I though: no need for using any package, in a POST call to a route I just found the file ready to be used in `req.files`!  I could access the full path at `req.files.upload.path`.

Very easy!